# Overriding current theme files via plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am creating a simple 404 redirect plugin.
I want the theme 404.php file to be override when I activate the plugin.
There is a 404.php page in the plugin files. File path: plugins/myplugin/files/404.php

How to override 404.php file in theme files with 404.php in plugin folder (When I activate the plugin).

I just created the plugin and activated it. All codes are here:

```
function my_redicert_plugin() {
global $wpdb;

$table_namex = $wpdb->prefix . 'redirect_p';

$charset_collatex = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

$sqlx = "CREATE TABLE $table_namex  (
    `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `mytext` longtext NOT NULL,
    `okbutton` longtext NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sqlx ); 
}


register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_redicert_plugin' );


add_action('admin_menu', 'ds_menux');

function ds_menux() {
    add_menu_page('404 Redirect', '404 Redirect', 'administrator', 'my-redirect-plugin', 'my_r_plugin', 'dashicons-admin-generic'); 
}
```

(Sorry my English.)

Comment: What exactly have you done? Show some code.

Comment: @SamuelAsor I have just created the plugin yet. All I want is to change this 404 file when I activate this plugin. (I've added all the codes.)

Comment: See this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404page/)

Answer (score 1):

Template logic is primarily controlled by `template-loader.php`.

The part you are interested in would be `get_404_template()`, which passes on to generic `get_query_template()` with number of hooks to override the logic and result.

`{$type}_template` (so `404_template`) filter would probably do it.